# Unix Timestamp: Difference between using ToUnixTimeMilliseconds and TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am converting a DateTime to Unix time. As I understand these two ways should return teh same result.

Option 1

```
DateTime dtfoo = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20);
DateTimeOffset dtfoo2 = new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo).ToUniversalTime();
long afoo = dtfoo2.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

Option 2

```
DateTime dtfoo = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20);
DateTimeOffset dtfoo2 = new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo).ToUniversalTime();
long afoo = (Int64)(dtfoo2.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Option 1 returns 1287525600000 and Option2 returns 1287529200000.

Why am I getting different results?

Comment: FYI, the source for `ToUnitTimeMilliseconds` is here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/DateTimeOffset.cs#L738

Comment: What happens if you `Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime())`?

Comment: The source code tells: " Truncate sub-millisecond precision before offsetting by the Unix Epoch to avoid the last digit being off by one for dates that result in negative Unix times". Is it because of this truncate that I am loosing precision?

Comment: @CompuChip: The result is the same as Option2

Comment: And, maybe both results are incorrect. Shouldn't it be 1287532800000? At least 4 online unix timestamp converters say that.

Comment: 1287532800000 is GMT. But in my time zone the date 20. October 2010 00:00:00 is 1287525600000.

Comment: ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() has the advantage that you won't accidentally use new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).  That is not UTC.  new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) is UTC.

Comment: So, for Dates after 01.01.1970 the method `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` works as expected. For dates before 01.01.1970 using the method `Substract` and ? `TotalMilliseconds` works. I am getting the expected Date in my time zone. But why?

Comment: The issue is to do with local/universal `DateTime` objects in use in your code, and how `new DateTimeOffset(dateTime)` works if you do not specify an offset. I've got a small example [here](https://rextester.com/TVGF21032) and will post an answer in full this evening.

Comment: Do you have more concerns regarding this issue?

Comment: I have a problem when my client is getting a negative duration and I try to interpret it with `momenjtjs`. I am getting the date of yesterday at 23:00, when I am sending a date before 1.1.1970. I have to analyze, which unix timestamp exactly I am sending....I am confused.

Comment: I'd recommend instead using an ISO8601 date time (i.e. `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")`) instead. `momentjs` works well with them and, to be honest, it's the future vs unix timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notice:** I am in UTC+9, and the root of your issues come from timezone offsets, so understand that the unix times I see may differ slightly from your own.

---

The difference lies in how you're handling your date objects. I'm assuming from the resultant difference that your timezone is CET (or you were using rextester, which I believe is in Germany).

Consider the following code:

```
var dtfoo = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20);
var dtfoo2 = new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo);
var dtfoo3 = dtfoo2.ToUniversalTime();
```

1. The first line creates a `DateTime` with a [`DateTimeKind` of "Unspecified"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_).
2. The second line creates a `DateTimeOffset` object from this. Because the DateTimeKind is Unspecified, the system time offset from UTC is used.
3. The third line converts this date into UTC.

Quoting the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset__ctor_System_DateTime_) for #2:

> If the value of DateTime.Kind is DateTimeKind.Local or DateTimeKind.Unspecified, the DateTime property of the new instance is set equal to dateTime, and the Offset property is set equal to the offset of the local system's current time zone.

Now let's write out the roundtrip format date string for 1-3:

```
2010-10-20T00:00:00.0000000
2010-10-20T00:00:00.0000000+09:00
2010-10-19T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
```

I'm in UTC+9, so the `DateTimeOffset` was rightly created with an offset of +9h. Converting that to universal takes us to 3pm on the 19th. Unfortunately, this causes the output of `.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()` to be `1287500400000`, which is `2010-10-19T15:00:00Z`. The value has become dependent on the machine's timezone.

So, now let's take a look at your second example:

```
DateTime dtfoo = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20);
DateTimeOffset dtfoo2 = new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo).ToUniversalTime();
long afoo = (Int64)(dtfoo2.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalMilliseconds;
```

OK, let's split this into the different parts so that we can see what time the system thinks they represent (remember that I'm in UTC+9):

1. `new DateTime(2010, 10, 20).ToString("o")` - 2010-10-20T00:00:00.0000000
2. `new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo).ToString("o")` - 2010-10-20T00:00:00.0000000+09:00
3. `new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo).ToUniversalTime()` - 2010-10-19T15:00:00.0000000+00:00
4. `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToString("o")` - 1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000

So you're effectively performing this calculation:

```
(DateTimeOffset.Parse("2010-10-19T15:00:00.0000000+00:00") - DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00.0000000")).TotalMilliseconds
```

This outputs `1287532800000`, which equates to 2010-10-20T00:00:00Z. This gives you the correct result because of how the subtraction is done:

1. The `DateTime` is [implicitly cast](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs#L792-L794) to a `DateTimeOffset`, equivalent to `new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000"))` - this means that both input dates have been through the same timezone changes.
2. The two dates for [subtraction](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs#L805-L807) are both converted to `DateTime` objects by calling the `DateTimeOffset`'s `.UtcDateTime` property.

So how can we fix your original example? We can take the local timezone offset out of the equation by specifying the offset when constructing the `DateTimeOffset`:

```
DateTime dtfoo = new DateTime(2010, 10, 20);
DateTimeOffset dtfoo2 = new DateTimeOffset(dtfoo, TimeSpan.Zero).ToUniversalTime();
long afoo = dtfoo2.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

This now gives us the same value as we got in the previous test: `1287532800000`. If we simplify this by using `DateTimeOffset.Parse` we should confirm that we're on the right track:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Parse("2010-10-20T00:00:00Z").ToUnixTimeMilliseconds());
```

And we can see that this also outputs `1287532800000`.

So, to conclude, your issue stems from how the `DateTimeOffset(datetime)` constructor handles dates with DateTimeKind `Unspecified` or `Local`. It skews your resulting universal time depending on your machine's timezone. This leads to an incorrect unix time offset. To solve it simply create your `DateTimeOffset` in one of the ways I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

The difference could be because `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` does not take leap seconds in to account.

here is what documentation says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2

> Unix time represents the number of seconds that have elapsed since
>   1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (January 1, 1970, at 12:00 AM UTC). It does not
>   take leap seconds into account. This method returns the number of
>   milliseconds in Unix time.

Where as `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` did not speak about that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds?view=netframework-4.7.2

> This property converts the value of this instance from ticks to
>   milliseconds. This number might include whole and fractional
>   milliseconds.

Comment: `It does not take leap seconds into account`: what are they exactly meaning?

Comment: If the issue was leap seconds, then I would expect a difference of a few seconds (27), not exactly 1 hour.